# True or False: $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=3 \Rightarrow \; f(0)=0 $ and $f'(0)=3$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

**Prove or contradict:**
$f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=3 \Rightarrow \; f(0)=0 $ and $f'(0)=3$

**My answer:**
True and below the proof:
If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ it means $f'(0)$ exists and verifies: $f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{f(0)}{x}$.
As by assumption it is given that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists and equal to $3$ and because $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ hence $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ and so $f(0)$ exits it cames by limit arithmetic that: $f'(0)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}-\frac{f(0)}{x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}-\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(0)}{x}=3-\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(0)}{x}$
Now if $f(0) \neq 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(0)}{x} = +- \infty$ and so in such case $f'(0)$ will not exist. That's why $f(0)=0$ and if $f(0)=0$ it cames naturally that $f'(0)=3$.

Q.E.D

Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: I think it can be improved in a few ways.  For example, the equality $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} - \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(0)}{x}$ requires that you already know that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0)}{x}$ exists.    So, I'd probably rewrite that portion as follows:  Because both $f'(0)$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exist, so does $f'(0) - \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0)}{x}$.

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=3$ implies $f(0)=0$. Nothing to do with derivative.

Comment: @BobDobbs Why? It is given that: $f'(0)$ exists and so:$f'(0)= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-0}{x}$ as we just showed that $f(0)=0$

Comment: @JasonDeVito  Thank a lot. Please can you writte an answer so i can mark this topic as solved?

Comment: @BobDobbs You are very wrong. Why must $f$ be continuous at $0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: if $f$ is differentiable at $0$ then it is continuous at $0$ and hence $f(x) \to f(0)$ as $x\to 0$. So BobDobbs approach is simpler and correct,  but perhaps they went overboard with "nothing to do with derivative"

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm certainly aware of all that. But people need to learn to avoid false statements here. 40+ years as a math professor have taught me to be careful.

Comment: You can proceed more directly by writing "$f$ is continuous at $0$ and hence $f(0)$ exists and $f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}x\cdot\frac{f(x)}{x}$" and apply product rule. The indirect argument about what happens if $f(0)\neq 0$ seems complicated to me (but it is more popular among many users here).

Comment: @TedShifrin: fully agree with you. I think many students don't explicitly state what they are assuming or what results they are using and are more interested in jumping to the right answer as fast as possible.

Comment: @TedShifrin I assumed it since limit exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable at $0,$ then $f$ is continuous at $0.$
Indeed
$$\lim_{x\to 0}[f(x)-f(0)]=\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)-f(0)\over x}x=f'(0)\cdot 0=0$$
Then
$$f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)\over x}x= 3\cdot 0=0$$
Thus $$f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)-f(0)\over x}=\lim_{x\to 0}{f(x)\over x}=3$$

Comment: Nice answer & redaction, thk a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You must take into account that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(0)}{x}$ exists iff $f(0)=0$ (it is wrong $f(0)\neq0$ implies $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(0)}{x}=\pm\infty$).

I argue as follows: by hypothesis, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=f'(0)$ exists and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=3$. By the algebra of limits, we have
\begin{gather*}
f'(0)-3=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=-\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(0)}{x}.
\end{gather*}
Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(0)}{x}$ exists iff $f(0)=0$ and in that case the limit value is zero, we conclude that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=3$.

Comment: $\sqrt{0}=0$ but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$ does not exist.

Comment: Thank for your answer but why it is wrong that $f(0)=c \neq 0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{c}{x} = \pm  \infty $? Have you any exemple to give me?

Comment: @BobDobbs Thk for your help. Yes but $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ ($f'(0)$ does not exist).

Comment: I wrote for Michael's answer. @X0-user-0X

Comment: @BobDobbs thk but to which part of his answer it is relevant?

Comment: First sentence...

Comment: @BobDobbs thank a lot for your time

Comment: @X0-user-0X $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}$ does not exist since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}=\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$.

Comment: Yes of course i know that what I ve written